# Tracking banner impressions and clicks on external website with javascript

Tags: javascript, html, regex, security, xss

I am serving some banners to external 3rd party websites and need to track impressions and clicks per website and also need to modify the banner images and links from time to time without requesting the 3rd parties to do this on their websites

I have come up with the following that tracks the clicks using GA campaigns and tracks the impressions as requests in IIS logs on my server.

HTML to include on external 3rd party websites

```
<div id="affBanner" style="width:500px"></div>
<script src="http://www.mywebsite.com/affiliates.js"></script>
```

Contents of affiliates.js

```
var affHost = window.location.hostname.replace(/[^0-9a-zA-Z]/g, "");
var affBanner = document.getElementById('affBanner');
affBanner.innerHTML = '<a href="http://mywebsite.com?utm_source='+affHost+'"  target="_blank"><img src="http://mywebsite.com/images/banner.jpg?aff='+affHost+'" alt="" style="width:100%;" /></a>';
```

This is working but I have 2 questions.

1. I am gathering input in the form of the hostname and then sanitizing it with a regex before using it in the banner link href and the image source. Is this code vulnerable XSS or other attack?
2. Does anyone have any suggestions how this code could be improved or another method of achieving a similar result? Please keep in mind I am trying to make this as simple as possible.

Comment: Don’t replace stuff, just simply URL-encode the values properly.

Comment: @CBroe so you would recommend just changing the first line to `var affHost = encodeURIComponent(window.location.hostname);`. Is this personal preference, performance, best practice, etc? Thanks

Comment: It’s the only thing that makes sense, because the (primary) _context_ you want to put the value in _is_ a URL. (The secondary context is HTML, but a URL-encoded value can not contain any characters any more that would be dangerous in that context.)

Comment: @CBroe Thanks for your input, I take your point and can see where you are coming from. Wouldn't necessarily agree it's the only thing that makes sense.

Comment: Well what else would in your opinion?

Comment: @CBroe The regex also makes sense to me as it serves the purpose, as far as know. Not saying it is the better solution.

Comment: No, it would simply get you _wrong_ data if it was to delete characters from the hostname.

Comment: @CBroe the data is only required to identify a small number of websites so in my use case would serve its purpose fine

Comment: Anyway, why go with the second-best solution that “somehow achieves the goal”, when there is a simple way to do it _right_ …?

Comment: @CBroe I am not saying I will be going with the second-best solution, I am simply saying that the URL endoding is not necessarily the only thing that makes sense. I appreciate your help on this and also your further explanations.

Comment: I already explained why it is the only thing that makes sense IMHO. Everything else is just a case of _“well it works, so I’ll take it.”_

Comment: @CBroe I know you already explained your opinion, I was saying that I appreciated that.